# Why is my unit test failing with "URI is not absolute" when I try to mock RestTemplate.postForEntity()?

Tags: java, mockito, resttemplate

I want to mock the postForEntity method of a RestTemplate instance variable belonging to one of my classes, but it keeps failing with a "URI is not absolute" error despite my seeing anyString() being passed in as the URI in other examples. Something that should be noted is that I did not @Mock my RestTemplate, because I want to test if it's been correctly built by the constructor of its parent class (namely the timeout).

I can't post actual code but the class I'm testing looks something like this:

```
public class MyClient {
    ...
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    public MyClient(Property x, Property y, Property z){
        this.x = x; 
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z; 
    }

    //New constructor that I want to test 
    public MyClient(Property x, Property y, Property z, int timeout){
        this(x, y, z);
        this.restTemplate =((SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory)getRestTemplate().getRequestFactory()).setReadTimeout(timeout);
    }
    
    public makeRequests() {
        ...
        //myEndpoint, myRequest are assigned earlier in this fx, CustomResponse is a custom class
        ResponseEntity resEntity = getRestTemplate().postForEntity(myEndpoint, myRequest, CustomResponse.class);
    }
}
```

I want to test whether MyClient.restTemplate is timing out:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest extends TestCase{
    ...
    
    @Test
    public void test_new_constructor(){
        MyClient myClient = new MyClient(x, y, z, 1000);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = myClient.getRestTemplate(); 
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), any(Class.class))).thenAnswer(new AnswersWithDelay(100000, new Returns(new ResponseEntity(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK)) ));
        //Will eventually add a delay to trigger a timeout + code for checking the exception, but it doesn't make it past the above line
        myClient.makeRequests();
    }
}
```

It fails on the `Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), any(Class.class))).thenAnswer(new AnswersWithDelay(100000, new Returns(new ResponseEntity(CustomResponse, HttpStatus.OK)) ));` line with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute`, why is this? Is it a bad idea to test an actual RestTemplate in the first place? I was thinking that using `Mockito.when` on the network calls would make it so that the tests aren't reliant on requests to actual endpoints, but is this not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't mocked an instance, you cannot call `when` with it. `when` is reserved for mock objects or spies.

The line `Mockito.when(restTemplate.postForEntity(anyString(), any(), any(Class.class)))` calls the real `postForEntity` method with parameters `anyString(), any(), any(Class.class)`, which is really just `"", null, null`:

[`ArgumentMatchers#anyString`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.java#L392):

```
public static String anyString() {
    reportMatcher(new InstanceOf(String.class, "<any string>"));
    return "";
}
```

[`#any`](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/blob/main/src/main/java/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.java#L140):

```
public static <T> T any() {
    reportMatcher(Any.ANY);
    return null;
}
```

The empty string `""` obviously isn't an absolute URI.

If you want to test a class, you must not mock it; otherwise you would only be testing the mock object/mock behavior and not your real class.

That said, I think it is fair to assume that `RestTemplate` has already been thoroughly tested by the framework authors – why do you want to test if it detects/triggers timeouts correctly? That should already be covered by the tests for `RestTemplate`.

If, however, you want to test if your application code handles timeouts of `RestTemplate` correctly, then by all means create a mock instance of `RestTemplate`, set it up to behave like it timeouted, and verify that your own code handles the timeout of the template correctly.